# How to find dll loaded by a process in AIX?

Tags: dll, debugging, aix

How to find which dynamic libs .so are loaded currently by a process, also those dll are dynamically loaded with dllopen.
I want to debug a process to find out which libs its using currently.

Comment: does AIX has a /proc/pid/maps you can parse?

Comment: this worked, but can't accept comments :(

Comment: For future refence for anyone reaching this page, newer versions of AIX 6.1 and higher, have the procldd <pid> command to get this info.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command on a *Nix system to tell you what libraries are included and their memory addresses.

```
ldd /path/to/your/binary
```

Comment: The question is about those dll that are dynamically loaded with dllopen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at liberty to simply restart the process, I believe AIX has an strace command (I know it has an equivalent otherwise, but it's been a few years).  Run a "grep \.so" on the sys call trace output to see exactly which file it opens.